# Adding a leading character and zeros for a column in hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How do I add a leading character and zeros to in order to get a string of length 4, as given below

```
8039 - T8039
79 - T0079
765 - T0765
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lpad()`:

```
select concat('T', lpad(val, 4, '0'))
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: @ReemaRodrigues Can you please mark this question as complete if this answer solves your problem.